# 'Tainted canvases may not be exported' Error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a web app that searches NASA's api and gets an image.  That image is then painted to a canvas element and the user can make adjustments and edit the image.  I am trying to take a snapshot of the final image and open it in another browser tab via canvas.toDataURL() but am getting a 'Tainted canvases may not be exported' error.  I did not see anything about jsonp in the api docs.  I am using the fetch api in react as seen below:

```
fetchPOD = (date) => {
        let that = this;
        fetch('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?&date=' + date + API_KEY)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(resp => {
    let link = resp.url;
    if(resp.media_type === 'image'){
            let noImage = document.getElementsByClassName('no-image')[0];
            noImage.style.display = 'none';
            that.setState({
                pod: resp.url,
                podTitle: resp.title
            })
        } else {
            that.setState({
                pod: 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1709/EclipseClimber_Struder_1080.jpg',
                nonImageLink: link,
                podTitle: 'A Hiker and the Eclipse'
            })
            let noImage = document.getElementsByClassName('no-image')[0];
            noImage.style.display = 'block';
        }

    })
};
```

I am not running a server on this app.  Any other way around this?

Comment: no, there is no way a Client can "bypass" the resource protection mechanism afforded by CORS

Comment: Are these image resources served with the 'allow-origin' headers? When do you set the img's src?

Comment: It seems they don't so nevermind... You would need at least a proxy server.